# What are public/packs and public/packs-test for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

When using *webpack*, the *webpacker* gem and Rails 5.1, I notice that running *rspec* for the first time generates **public/packs** and **public/packs-test**.

- What are these directories for?
- What is the difference between the two?
- Should they be tracked by version control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/public` folder in Rails is where precompiled assets go for static distribution (aka compiled once on server start so they're not compiled on every page load). This is a feature of the [Rails asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to help speed up asset distribution so Rails doesn't have to serve them itself.

Note how `webpacker` assets are placed in `packs` folders in your `/app/assets` directory. These packs will be precompiled and placed into the `/public/packs` folder from which these precompiled packs will go and be served from during page requests.

The `/public/packs-test` folder is where test environment packs will be precompiled to. You can configure the location of precompiled packs per environment in the [config/webpacker.yml](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/lib/install/config/webpacker.yml) file.

---

As to whether to track these files by version control, that's up to you—and it's usually a logistical question on what you need to do when you deploy to production. From the official Ruby on Rails Guide:

> There are several reasons why you might want to precompile your assets locally. Among them are:
>
> - You may not have write access to your production file system.
> - You may be deploying to more than one server, and want to avoid duplication of work.
> - You may be doing frequent deploys that do not include asset changes.
>
> Local compilation allows you to commit the compiled files into source control, and deploy as normal.

[See the official Ruby on Rails Guide section 4.2 on Local Precompilation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#local-precompilation) for more reasons why (or why not) you'd want to precompile and commit the generated files into version control.